# Using the word "surgery" as an adjective

Tags: adjectives

My university lecturer (for an engineering module) frequently organizes "surgery classes" where he answers any questions we might have or goes through some extra problem sheets. Essentially, the "surgery classes" are unstructured lecture slots during which anything can be done.

Question - Why use the term "surgery class"? What does it mean when someone uses the word "surgery" as an adjective and why can one use surgery as an adjective?

Comment: Why not? It is a noun (an a place of operation in a British hospital). You have gymnastic classes in a gym - gymnasts perform gymnastic. Surgeons perform surgery in a surgery

Comment: Surgery here is the broader sense where problems are addressed and hopefully rectified. MPs run surgeries for constituents in the UK. // Most (possibly all) nouns can be used as premodifiers of head nouns. _football manager / blood bank / tree surgeon_ ....

Comment: *Surgical* is the adjectival form of surgery in some cases but not all cases: it's mainly used in conjunction with surgeons and operating theatres and veterinary surgeons, not with other types of surgery (buildings, practices, events). Even in medicine, if you were talking about a GP's surgery you might want to be careful to differentiate the building where a GP sees people, examines, and prescribes, from things relating to cutting people open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am familiar with the *noun* 'surgery' being used in this sense, but not so much with the *adjective*, as in 'surgery classes'.

Here is an article (from a US dictionary) that explains the use of the term in British English.

> **Surgery - The word has a special meaning in British English**
> 16 Jun 2016
>
> ...a regular gathering known in Britain as a surgery, which means “a
> special period of time when people can visit [someone] to ask
> questions.”
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/news-trend-watch/surgery-2016-06-16

I am British and so I'm used to hearing this to mean that people have a time when they can consult with an expert. Originally the expert would have been a medical doctor, but now it can refer to any such meeting. A lecturer can hold a surgery to help students, a member of parliament can hold a surgery to be attended by their constituents, etc.

The meaning has been expanded here: A doctor sees one patient at a time. An MP sees one constituent at a time. Your lecturer seems to use it to refer to meeting more than one student at a time.